# Query to get the count of logins by a user within a set time interval from previous login

Tags: mysql, database

I want to get a count of how many times a user logs in within, let's say, 5 hours from the previous login.

So something like `new_login - old_login < 5 hours`.

The login table would have `user_id` and `time_accessed`.

This query is to get the count of user logins within a day. I can't figure out how to compare the different times within the same column within the same statement:

```
SELECT user_id, date(time_accessed), count(user_id) AS login_within_5_hour_period
FROM login
GROUP BY user_id, date(time_accessed)
ORDER BY time_accessed;
```

*Sample input*

```
+---------+---------------------+
| user_id |    time_accessed    |
+---------+---------------------+
| 1       | 2020-02-19 09:00:00 |
| 1       | 2020-02-19 12:00:00 |
| 1       | 2020-02-19 13:00:00 |
| 1       | 2020-02-19 19:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

*Sample ouput*

```
+---------+---------------------+----------------------------+
| user_id | date(time_accessed) | login_within_5_hour_period |
+---------+---------------------+----------------------------+
| 1       | 2020-02-19          | 3                          |
| 1       | 2020-02-19          | 1                          |
+---------+---------------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compare different times, you need to join the table with itself.

The following query will find the number of logins by the user within 5 hours, **excluding** the current login. If you want to include the current login in the count, change this `l1.time_accessed > l2.time_accessed` to `l1.time_accessed >= l2.time_accessed`.

```
SELECT l1.user_id, l1.time_accessed, COUNT(l2.user_id) AS login_within_5_hour_period
FROM logins l1
LEFT JOIN logins l2
    ON l1.user_id = l2.user_id
    AND l1.time_accessed > l2.time_accessed
    AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(l1.time_accessed, l2.time_accessed)) / 3600 <= 5
GROUP BY l1.user_id, l1.time_accessed;
```

This second query will return a single result, showing the number of logins by the user within 5 hours of the time specified.

```
SELECT l1.user_id, l1.time_accessed, COUNT(l2.user_id) AS login_within_5_hour_period
FROM logins l1
LEFT JOIN logins l2
    ON l1.user_id = l2.user_id
    AND l1.time_accessed > l2.time_accessed
    AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(l1.time_accessed, l2.time_accessed)) / 3600 <= 5
WHERE l1.time_accessed = '2020-02-19 19:00:00'
GROUP BY l1.user_id, l1.time_accessed;
```

Working example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g7jDYqoKn38iQTFuPjej9m/1

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to remove duplicates and just get the total count?

Comment: @J.Chan - what results do you feel are duplicated? Did you notice that the login time is different for each result, and the count shows the number of logins in the 5 hours prior to that login?

Comment: is there a way to make it non-relative to each login such that it only takes the total sum of the logins in the time interval? So that count returns 3 instead of 3-2-1 for each login? Because I only need to check the total logins and not the individual logins.

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense. At 9:00am, there were no previous logins within 5 hours. At 12:00pm, there was one previous login within 5 hours. At 13:00pm, there were two previous logins within 5 hours. And at 19:00pm, there were again no previous logins within 5 hours. Do you want just one result? If yes, the query can be modified to take the time of the current login.

Comment: @J.Chan - see my updated answer. Using the second query, you can pass the current login time, and it'll return the number of logins in the 5 hours prior.